# Apply Easing Function to DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Animation in Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, animation, storyboard

```
<Storyboard x:Name="stTOPAni">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="grdOverlay">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Thickness>0</Thickness>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Name="key1" KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Thickness>0,-500,0,0</Thickness>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>

            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Thickness>0,-800,0,0</Thickness>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>
```

I want to change Top margin using this storyboard, so I applice KeyFrame Animation, But its not using EasingFunction and hence is not smooth, How would I apply Easing Function to make the Animation smooth!

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you would simple use one of the ...ThicknessKeyFrames.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="stTOPAni" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DiscreteThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
            <DiscreteThicknessKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteThicknessKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteThicknessKeyFrame>
        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
            </EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,-800,0,0</Thickness>
            </EasingThicknessKeyFrame.Value>
        </EasingThicknessKeyFrame>
    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

But unfortunatly in Silverlight the animation can not be smooth because you have to use an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` for `Thickness` animation which [only supports discrete interpolation method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189038%28v=VS.95%29.aspx#animation_types). [`EasingFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308751.aspx) also not supported.